# Average of a sequence of integers using divide and conquer

Tags: java, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Given a sequence of integers, how can I find the average of it using a divide and conquer approach? I have to write a method "double avg(int[] a, int l, int r)" that finds the average in the array A, spanning from 'l' to 'r' as homework, but I get a StackOverflowError on the first recursive call - not in the second, though! - of my code, and I can't seem to understand why. Also, I'm pretty sure it doesn't give me a true average, but I found no way to check the average of a sequence using the divide and conquer. Here is my code:

```
public class Average {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
    int l = 0;
    int r = A.length-1;
    System.out.println("Average of the array: "+averageCheck(A, l, r));

}

public static double averageCheck(int[] A, int l, int r) {
    if (l==r) {
        return A[l];
    }
    // Base Case: if there's just a single element it is the average of the array itself

    int mid = (l+r)/2;
    double avLeft = 0;
    double avRight = 0;

    avLeft = A[l]/r + averageCheck(A, l, mid);
    avRight = A[mid+1]/r + averageCheck(A, mid+2, r);

    double average = ( (avLeft*mid) + (avRight * (r-mid) ) ) /r;

    return average;

    }
}
```

Comment: (Not the cause of the `StackOverflowError`) The average of a sequence of integers is the sum divided by the length. Don't do the division until the end. Particularly don't divide by `r`, that is meaningless.

Comment: Two hints: consider writing unit test - such code is perfect for that. For the exception itself ... that typically means that you created an infinite recursion. Meaning: your code is missing conditions to **stop** the recursion. So, step one: add print statements for your variables, and/or run it in a debugger.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I had read somewhere that the sum of Element/Lenght done for every element is the average, so I thought it was real. I'll try with a normal average now, but it's even harder to imagine it recursively.

Comment: The r stands for "right", not "real", and you are doing integer division also, so don't be surprised if you don't get the exact answer

Comment: @cricket_007 true that, but I still don't get the average. Am I doing something wrong calculating it? Any idea how to change it, and still use the divide and conquer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursivity does not end when `r == l + 1`. In this case, `mid == l` and in the second recursive call, `mid+2` will be greater than r. Add this at the beginning of the function:

```
if(l > r)
       return 0;
```

Example, imagine `l == 5` and `r == 6`, then `mid` will have the value 5. The second call will be `averageCheck(A, 7, 6)` as `mid+2` is 7. In this call, the condition  `l == r` will be `false`. Continue in the same logic and you will find that the recursivity will not end.

I think also that it would be better if you calculate the sum recursively and divide by the length at the end.

I suggest this solution:

```
public class Average {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
    System.out.println("Average of the array: "+average(A));

}

public static double average (int[] A) {
       return averageCheck(A, 0, A.length - 1) / A.length;
}

public static double averageCheck(int[] A, int l, int r) {

if (l > r)
    return 0;

if (l==r) {
    return A[l];
}
// Base Case: if there's just a single element it is the average of the array itself

int mid = (l+r)/2;
double avLeft = 0;
double avRight = 0;

avLeft = averageCheck(A, l, mid);
avRight = averageCheck(A, mid+1, r);

double average = avLeft + avRight;

return average;

}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain it better? I don't get where 'r = l + 1' is, nor 'mid == l'. The second call works, but the average is not the expected one, it's just a double created by my bad math on the code.

Comment: I added an example to the answer.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi The diagnosis is correct, the suggested solution is not ideal though. I'd rather sort out the ranges **before** splitting.